# How to add/remove style with two buttons with Vue

Tags: vue.js

I got two buttons "+", "-" plus should display block, minus display none. I created snipplet in vanilla js and I don't know how to make it work in Vue.js. In Vue I got one component with +, which open component with -. Minus should close current component where - is inside this component, which opened +.

```js
var p = document.querySelector(".plus");
var m = document.querySelector(".minus");
var div = document.querySelector("div");

p.addEventListener("click", p => {
  div.style.display = "block";
});

m.addEventListener("click", m => {
  div.style.display = "none";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="plus">+</button>
    <button class="minus">-</button>
    <div
      style="height: 500px; width: 500px; background-color: blueviolet; display: none"
    ></div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is using `display: none` a requirement or would removing it completely using `v-if` be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but if i use it, i need to click 2 times on button.

Comment: Could you please provide the code from your best attempt to implement this in Vue? In its present form this isn't really a question, you're just asking us to write your code for you.

Comment: Ok, no problem. :) There is mu vue: https://jsfiddle.net/sq6yvau9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood the question correctly then you should just need the child component to emit an event when the `-` button is clicked. The parent component holds the relevant state and should update that state when that event occurs.

In my example I have used `v-if` rather than `v-show`. Using `v-show` would set `display: none`, whereas `v-if` removes the child component completely, including the corresponding DOM nodes. Either would work for such a simple example.

```js
Articles = {
  template: `
    <div>
      <button @click="onCloseClick">- Close</button>
      <p>Other stuff</p>
    </div>
  `,
  
  methods: {
    onCloseClick () {
      this.$emit('close')
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  components: {
    Articles
  },
  
  data () {
    return {
      isActive: false
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="isActive = true">+ Expand</button>
  <Articles
    v-if="isActive"
    @close="isActive = false"
  ></Articles>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start understanding vueJS conditional rendering would be [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html).

```js
// In your index.js file 

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    // create a data binding to display or hide the div
    displayDiv: false
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <button class="plus" @click="displayDiv = true">+</button>
      <button class="minus" @click="displayDiv = false">-</button>
      <!-- I added an addition button to toggle the display --> 
      <button class="toggle" @click="displayDiv = !displayDiv">Toggle</button>
      <div
        v-if="displayDiv"
        style="height: 500px; width: 500px; background-color: blueviolet;"
      ></div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively you could use [dynamic css](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) to dynamically add or remove a css class that hides the div on load and only displays when the "+" button is pressed.

Comment: Thank you, but It still doesn't fix my issue. I got this button in different components and i can't access displayDiv: false, I already did what u send, but I can't fix it between these two components.